# Efficiently getting string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take two values from string
"105.106"

The values 105 and 106 can be different the point(.) will decide their splitting after split i want these values in variable. i have look it into indexOf and split method but not getting logic.

Comment: Define "not getting logic". What don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
var str    = "105.106";
var values = str.split('.');  // (or "." or /\./)
console.log(values[0]);       // Output: 105
console.log(values[1]);       // Output: 106
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/NVrXQ/1/)

Comment: This is incorrect. /./ will match every character, making it split on any character at all.

Comment: Use `"."`, not `/./` - the latter will match and split on every character.

Answer (score 3):

You can learn more about how `split` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split). In short, `split` is a method on the `String`'s prototype that you pass it the character that acts as a delimiter, and it tokenizes the string based on that character. For example, if you had `"123,456,789"` and you wanted to tokenize the string as if the `,` was the delimiter, you would get `"123"`, `"456"`, and `"789"`.

Now your string is `"105.106"`, and you want `.` to act as the delimiter, as such you write something similar to:

```
tokens = "105.106".split(".");
tokens[0] == "105"; // true
tokens[1] == "106"; // true
```

As you can see, `split` has decomposed the string into an array with two components, containing the string splited by the `.` character.

Comment: Nitpicking, but it's a method of `String`'s prototype.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
var str = "105.106";

// does the string contain floating point dot ?
if (str.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
  var values = str.split('.');
  alert(values[0]); // value before dot
  alert(values[1]); // value after dot
}
else {
  alert(str);  // string did not contain a dot/point
}
```

Above code will give you both values before and after dot/point *in case it contains a dot* else it will give you string as it was.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript String.split(delimiter) method does what you want. Use it like this:

```
var s = "105.106";
var values = s.split(".");
// values[0] = "105", values[1] = "106".
```

Comment: [I guess you didn't try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSdm6/1/) Regexes are delimited by `/`, not `"`.

Comment: If you're referring to the typo, I fixed that within a couple of seconds of posting it...

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested it but guess this may work

```
var str="xxx.xxxxx";
dot=str.lastIndexOf('.');
num2=str.substring(dot+1);
num1=str.substring(0,dot);
```

Comment: this 1 will work for float numbers also like "23.45.234" will display 23.45 and 234 respectively

Comment: I'm not sure that fits in this case though, how would you even know whether "23.45.234" means 23.45 and 234, or 23 and 45.234? It would not be suitable to use "." as a separator if there was any possibility of floating point numbers.